# Strange model result from linear mixed effects model

Tags: r, mixed-model

I am using a linear mixed effects model (using lmer) to model the results of an experiment where we have two binary treatment variables A and B, and each participant completes four trials with random combinations of these variables. We are then looking for individual effects of A, B, and the interaction effect of A and B. These treatment variables are compared against the control variable which comes from the results in the first (non-manipulated) section of each trial. In lmer this is set as factor variable liek this:

```
exp$d <- factor(exp$treatment, labels = c("A1","A2","control"))
exp$d_t <- relevel(exp$d, "control")
```

In addition we include three other fixed effects of interest which are continuous, and two random effects in the final model.

The issue is that when I look at the summary of the final model, some of the tests do not appear: for example I might see the individual effect of A1, A2 and B1 but not B2.

To try to mitigate this I coded A and B as dummy variables such that we have 1 factor variable with options: A1B1, A1B2, A2B1, A2B2. In this case all the variables appear but when looking at the interaction of this dummy variable with the other fixed effects we check I find that the interaction effects end up strange and inconsistent with what is seen when graphing the data.

For example we get the result:

|  | Estimate |
| --- | --- |
| Intercept | 2.328e-01 |
| dw | 7.328e-01 |
| A1B1 | 3.446e-01 |
| A1B2 | -6.861e-02 |
| A2B1 | -2.402e-01 |
| A2B2 | 5.006e-01 |
| dw:A1B1 | -3.558e-01 |
| dw:A1B2 | 7.926e-02 |
| dw:A2B1 | 2.457e-01 |
| dw:A2B2 | -5.059e-01 |

I am confused about why the results with dw would be so close the inverse of the results without it.

When used not as a dummy variable we get something like:

|  | Estimate |
| --- | --- |
| Intercept | 2.328e-01 |
| dw | 7.472e-01 |
| A1 | -8.561e-02 |
| A2 | 3.006e-01 |
| B1 | -5.408e-01 |
| A1:B1 | 1.254e+00 |
| dw :A1 | 8.936e-02 |
| dw : A2 | -3.059e-01 |
| dw : B1 | 5.516e-01 |
| dw : A1: B1 | -1.262e+00 |

- note in this model B2 does not appear at all and the interaction effect of A2:B1 is also not shown. Why do these disappear and what can be done? Also why are the interaction effects almost always - values of the individual effects?

Am I making a mistake here? What is the best way to model this data in order to see the individual effects of A and B and interaction effect or to properly get the results of A and B as dummy variables (both options are equally fine for interpreting my results).

Comment: Have you looked at the frequencies of occurrence for these effects? Chances are there is no data to populate the cells due to an inadequate sample size.

Comment: The parameters in a model are 1 less than the number of classes. You can look up explanations for 'dummy encoding' to see more about this.

Comment: Re: Sextus Empiricus: That's fine: I also have a 'control' class and that one I don't expect to be shown.

Comment: Re: Mike hunter: the frequency of ocurrence for each treatment category is equal (and each have at least ±150 samples).

Comment: This is an interesting question, but there's not quite enough information here to figure out what's going on. Could you edit your question to show us the results of `with(your_data, table(treatmentA, treatmentB))`? Is there any chance you could share the data?